# Python: How to get raw audio file using pyaudio for use in pocketsphinx?

Tags: python, pyaudio, pocketsphinx

I was trying to get audio data in raw format using pyaudio, to then use in pocketsphinx for my project. However, when I use the raw file generated the output by this program the output contains random noise.

I want the raw file to be usable in pocketsphinx.

```
import pyaudio
import wave

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt32

CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 16000
CHUNK = 1024 
RECORD_SECONDS = 2

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# start Recording
stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
        rate=RATE, input=True,
        frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
print "recording..."
frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)
print "finished recording"


# stop Recording
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
audio.terminate()


file = open("newfile.raw", "w")
file.write(b''.join(frames))
file.close()
```

Comment: The code is correct, the hardware is probably broken, not the code.

Comment: It worked when I changed file = open("newfile.raw", "w") to file = open("newfile.raw", "wb"). Thanks for the replay anyway.